Capitulum symbol (⸿) in LaTeX
Is there a way to typeset the capitulum symbol (⸿) in LaTeX?
I couldn't spot it in the comprehensive symbols list, but then it's hard to know where in the 400+ pages to look.
I know a pilcrow can be set with \P, but \C doesn't have the same result for a capitulum.

On the command line, albatross ⸿ will return a list of fonts on your system that have the character (U+2E3F).

I found this site latexequation useful too, it is possible to draw the symbol and get the command.

If you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX then you can find a font that supplies the character, for example using the albatross tool. Then you can just input the character as it is.
Some examples:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\setmainfont{Arimo}
Capitulum in Arimo: ⸿

\setmainfont{Noto Sans}
Capitulum in Noto Sans: ⸿

\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
Capitulum in Noto Serif: ⸿

\setmainfont{Roboto Condensed}
Capitulum in Roboto Condensed: ⸿

\setmainfont{Tinos}
Capitulum in Tinos: ⸿
\end{document}



@rallg The link works for me.

have you tried detexify
maybe it is
\usepackage{ dsfont }
\mathds{C}
mathmode

However, yours is somewhat filled. If its not the right one, then maybe it does not exist in that list...
